# Code Optimization (Nested For Loops)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I am running a matlab code where I have to run nested for loops. I have done preallocation. I think vectorization is impossible in my case. Besides, I am not familiar with writing mex files. What would you suggest me to optimize my code in terms of speed? You can find the code below. It takes about 3-4 seconds with increasing tuple_rs and tuple_cs values.

```
for i=1:tuple_rs
mu=target.x{tID,tm-N+1};                    % Track at T(k-S+1)
sig=target.c{tID,tm-N+1};
    for n=1:tuple_cs
        if a(i,n)~=0                           % Non-Dummy Measurement
           v=bh{tm-N+n+1}(a(i,n),:)';          % Measurement
           mu = ml.FCV * mu;
           sig = ml.FCV * sig * ml.FCV'+ ml.Q;
           S = ml.H*sig*ml.H'+ml.Rsd;
           innv = mu(1:2) - v(1:2);
           eucdis=sqrt(innv * innv');          % Euclidean Distance
           % Eliminate measurements outside of the gate
           if eucdis > target.Kn_Thresh/2
              phi_n(tID,i)=10^-900; phi_o(tID,i)=1; 
              continue;
           end
           Sm=S(1:2,1:2); iv=v(1:2)-mu(1:2);
           lhood=(2*pi)^-1*det(Sm)^-0.5*exp(-0.5*(iv)'*(Sm\iv));% Cost
           Msd=target.Sp_Thresh - cf{tm-N+n+1}(a(i,n)); % Norm. Fs
           phi_o(tID,i)=phi_o(tID,i)*vol;      % Dummy Track
           phi_n(tID,i)=phi_n(tID,i)*PD*lhood*PM(n)*(Msd/SumSd(n)); % Nondummy T
           z_mu=[mu(1);mu(2);mu(3);mu(4)];     % Predicted Measurement
           S = ml.H*sig*ml.H'+ml.R;
           gain = (sig * ml.H')/S;             % Gain
           sig = sig - gain*ml.H*sig;          % Covariance estimation
           mu = mu + gain*(v-z_mu);            % Mean estimation
        else phi_n(tID,i)= phi_n(tID,i)*(1-PD)*PL(n); % Dummy Measurement
          phi_o(tID,i)=phi_o(tID,i)*1;
          mu = ml.FCV * mu;
          sig = ml.FCV * sig * ml.FCV'+ ml.Q;
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: Use `profile` to identify the slow lines.

Comment: I did it. The thing is each lines cost similar time. Like I said, the body of the for loop is not expensive but it becomes slower exponentially as i increase the number of iterations.

Comment: Try removing as many uses of `struct`s and `cell`s as you can, they can be inefficient sometimes.

Comment: also check if anything is growing inside the loop (using more memory)

Comment: what's the deal with `10^-900`?

Comment: It is just there to introduce a value near zero. Ok, I will try to eliminate growing arrays. However, once I checked the profile each line has similar run time.

Comment: can you provide a small set of input data?